# DIV CSS - Horizontal menu - How to define a selected item?

Tags: html, css, colors, menu

I was creating a horizontal menu by using HTML and CSS.
It's working fine.
1 thing I can't find (on the internet) is what I have to do to activate, to make 1 item 'active' when the menu is shown on the screen.

In other words: I want to have, in this case, 'Option 3' selected with a different color (eg. white as background, red as character color) than the other options.

I've added the simplified code I'm using.

Where do I have to change something?

Thanks a lot for your help.

### The code I'm using

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
    background-color: linen;
}

.fullBox {
 position:inherit;
 background-color:transparent;
}
.blockwhite{
 display:inline-block; 
 height:37px; 
 width:10px6%;
 color:white;
 border-bottom:none;
}
.fullBoxInner {
 position:inherit;
 width:100%;
 margin:0px auto;
    top: 63px; 
    left: 0px; 
}

#menu {
 margin-top:0px;
 padding:0;
 text-align:center;
 background-color: #000066C;
} 
#menu > div > div {
 display:inline-block;
 background-color: yellowgreen;
 width:19%;
 color:#fff;
 height:35px;
 line-height:35px;
 cursor:pointer;
 border-bottom:2px solid yellowgreen;
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
} 
#menu > div > div:hover, .persHoverM {
 color:green;
 background-color:#F5F5F5;
 border-bottom:2px solid red /*green*/;
} 
#menu > div > div:active {
 color:yellowgreen;
 border-bottom:2px solid bleu /*yellowgreen*/;
} 

</style>

</head>

<body>
          <div class="fullBox" id="menu">
             <div class="fullBoxInner">
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 1</div>
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 2</div>
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 3</div>
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 4</div>
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 5</div>
             </div>                       
           </div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Add a `class` to the element, like `<div class="persHoverM active">Option 3</div>`. Then in CSS: `.active{ color: red; background-color: white; }`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the class to the active item, for example:

```
<div class="fullBoxInner">
  <div class="persHoverM active">Option 1</div>
  <div class="persHoverM">Option 2</div>
  <div class="persHoverM">Option 3</div>
  <div class="persHoverM">Option 4</div>
  <div class="persHoverM">Option 5</div>
</div>   


.active {
  color: green;
  background-color:white;
}
```

Set this on each corresponding page and they will show as active, or you can dynamically change which item has the class with javascript/jquery

Comment: Dear Harvey (and lmgonzalves),

Thanks for your quick answer.

I tried it again, but I don't see any difference. All 5 options are still green.
What do I missing?

Comment: Is seems that '#menu > div > div ' overrides the .active class.

Comment: In that case try specifying a more specific class, for example #menu > div >div.active and then your styles for the active class. Also make sure that your active declaration is below the original styling in the css so that it is not overwritten

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child` selector.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
    background-color: linen;
}

.fullBox {
 position:inherit;
 background-color:transparent;
}
.blockwhite{
 display:inline-block; 
 height:37px; 
 width:10px6%;
 color:white;
 border-bottom:none;
}
.fullBoxInner {
 position:inherit;
 width:100%;
 margin:0px auto;
    top: 63px; 
    left: 0px; 
}

#menu {
 margin-top:0px;
 padding:0;
 text-align:center;
 background-color: #000066C;
} 
#menu > div > div {
 display:inline-block;
 background-color: yellowgreen;
 width:19%;
 color:#fff;
 height:35px;
 line-height:35px;
 cursor:pointer;
 border-bottom:2px solid yellowgreen;
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
} 
#menu > div > div:hover, .persHoverM {
 color:green;
 background-color:#F5F5F5;
 border-bottom:2px solid red /*green*/;
} 
#menu > div > div:active {
 color:yellowgreen;
 border-bottom:2px solid bleu /*yellowgreen*/;
} 

#menu div.persHoverM:nth-child(3) { /* selects third ".persHoverM" class div */
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
          <div class="fullBox" id="menu">
             <div class="fullBoxInner">
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 1</div>
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 2</div>
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 3</div>
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 4</div>
                <div class="persHoverM">Option 5</div>
             </div>                       
           </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot.